# Looped when trying to install `network-manager-sstp` dependencies as hinted by `./configure` output:

Tags: debian, dependencies, configure

I am trying to install [network-manager-sstp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sstp-client/files/), but I get looped trying to install the dependencies. `./configure` output oscillates between telling me I'm missing two distinct dependencies (`libnma` and `libnm-gtk`) - whenever I install one, it complains about not having the other, regardless of me having installed it a minute ago.

How does this happen and how can I fix it?

It goes like this:

```
$ ./configure

configure: error: Package requirements (libnm-gtk >= 1.2.0) were not met:

No package 'libnm-gtk' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBNM_GTK_CFLAGS
and LIBNM_GTK_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

... so I go install that

```
$ sudo apt-get install libnm-gtk-dev

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gir1.2-nm-1.0 : Breaks: gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 (< 1.8.0-2) but 1.6.2-3+deb9u2 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

... so I go ahead and install `gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0` :

```
$ sudo apt-get install gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gcr-3
  gir1.2-gdesktopenums-3.0 gir1.2-gdm-1.0 gir1.2-geoclue-2.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0
  gir1.2-graphene-1.0 gir1.2-gweather-3.0 gir1.2-json-1.0 gir1.2-mutter-7 gir1.2-polkit-1.0 gir1.2-rsvg-2.0
  gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 gjs gnome-backgrounds gnome-menus gnome-session-bin gnome-session-common
  gnome-shell-common gstreamer1.0-pipewire libcamel-1.2-62 libdbus-glib-1-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev-bin libebackend-1.2-10
  libebook-1.2-20 libebook-contacts-1.2-3 libecal-2.0-1 libedata-book-1.2-26 libedata-cal-2.0-1 libedataserver-1.2-25
  libedataserverui-1.2-2 libgdata-common libgdata22 libgdm1 libgjs0g libgnome-autoar-0-0 libmozjs-78-0 libmutter-7-0
  libnm-gtk0 mutter-common network-manager-dev switcheroo-control xwayland
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gir1.2-nm-1.0 gir1.2-nma-1.0 libnm-dev libnma-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 4 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/310 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10.9 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 348213 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libnma-dev:amd64 (1.8.30-1) ...
Removing libnm-dev:amd64 (1.30.0-2) ...
Removing gir1.2-nma-1.0:amd64 (1.8.30-1) ...
Removing gir1.2-nm-1.0:amd64 (1.30.0-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0:amd64.
(Reading database ... 347899 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0_1.6.2-3+deb9u2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0:amd64 (1.6.2-3+deb9u2) ...
Setting up gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0:amd64 (1.6.2-3+deb9u2) ...
```

... and then successfully complete the installation of libnm-gtk-dev

```
$ sudo apt-get install libnm-gtk-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gcr-3 gir1.2-gdesktopenums-3.0 gir1.2-gdm-1.0 gir1.2-geoclue-2.0
  gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-graphene-1.0 gir1.2-gweather-3.0 gir1.2-json-1.0 gir1.2-mutter-7 gir1.2-polkit-1.0 gir1.2-rsvg-2.0 gir1.2-soup-2.4
  gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 gjs gnome-backgrounds gnome-menus gnome-session-bin gnome-session-common gnome-shell-common gstreamer1.0-pipewire libcamel-1.2-62 libebackend-1.2-10
  libebook-1.2-20 libebook-contacts-1.2-3 libecal-2.0-1 libedata-book-1.2-26 libedata-cal-2.0-1 libedataserver-1.2-25 libedataserverui-1.2-2 libgdata-common libgdata22 libgdm1 libgjs0g
  libgnome-autoar-0-0 libmozjs-78-0 libmutter-7-0 mutter-common switcheroo-control xwayland
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0 libnm-glib-dev libnm-util-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0 libnm-glib-dev libnm-gtk-dev libnm-util-dev
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/992 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,471 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Selecting previously unselected package gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0:amd64.
(Reading database ... 347906 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0_1.4.4-1+deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0:amd64 (1.4.4-1+deb9u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnm-util-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libnm-util-dev_1.6.2-3+deb9u2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnm-util-dev:amd64 (1.6.2-3+deb9u2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnm-glib-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libnm-glib-dev_1.6.2-3+deb9u2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnm-glib-dev:amd64 (1.6.2-3+deb9u2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnm-gtk-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libnm-gtk-dev_1.4.4-1+deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnm-gtk-dev:amd64 (1.4.4-1+deb9u1) ...
Setting up gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0:amd64 (1.4.4-1+deb9u1) ...
Setting up libnm-util-dev:amd64 (1.6.2-3+deb9u2) ...
Setting up libnm-glib-dev:amd64 (1.6.2-3+deb9u2) ...
Setting up libnm-gtk-dev:amd64 (1.4.4-1+deb9u1) ...
```

...and try to configure again. Now I don't don't get the error anymore:

```
$ ./configure

No package 'libnma' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBNMA_CFLAGS
and LIBNMA_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

... so I go install `libnma`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libnma-dev
        
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gcr-3
  gir1.2-gdesktopenums-3.0 gir1.2-gdm-1.0 gir1.2-geoclue-2.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0
  gir1.2-graphene-1.0 gir1.2-gweather-3.0 gir1.2-json-1.0 gir1.2-mutter-7 gir1.2-polkit-1.0 gir1.2-rsvg-2.0
  gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 gjs gnome-backgrounds gnome-menus gnome-session-bin gnome-session-common
  gnome-shell-common gstreamer1.0-pipewire libcamel-1.2-62 libdbus-glib-1-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev-bin libebackend-1.2-10
  libebook-1.2-20 libebook-contacts-1.2-3 libecal-2.0-1 libedata-book-1.2-26 libedata-cal-2.0-1 libedataserver-1.2-25
  libedataserverui-1.2-2 libgdata-common libgdata22 libgdm1 libgjs0g libgnome-autoar-0-0 libmozjs-78-0 libmutter-7-0
  libnm-glib4 libnm-gtk0 libnm-util2 mutter-common network-manager-dev switcheroo-control xwayland
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-nm-1.0 gir1.2-nma-1.0 libnm-dev
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-nm-1.0 gir1.2-nma-1.0 libnm-dev libnma-dev
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 1 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/860 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 347906 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0:amd64 (1.6.2-3+deb9u2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gir1.2-nm-1.0:amd64.
(Reading database ... 347899 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gir1.2-nm-1.0_1.30.0-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gir1.2-nm-1.0:amd64 (1.30.0-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gir1.2-nma-1.0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../gir1.2-nma-1.0_1.8.30-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gir1.2-nma-1.0:amd64 (1.8.30-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnm-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libnm-dev_1.30.0-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnm-dev:amd64 (1.30.0-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnma-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libnma-dev_1.8.30-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnma-dev:amd64 (1.8.30-1) ...
Setting up gir1.2-nm-1.0:amd64 (1.30.0-2) ...
Setting up gir1.2-nma-1.0:amd64 (1.8.30-1) ...
Setting up libnm-dev:amd64 (1.30.0-2) ...
Setting up libnma-dev:amd64 (1.8.30-1) ...
```

... and try to configure again :

```
$ ./configure

configure: error: Package requirements (libnm-gtk >= 1.2.0) were not met:

No package 'libnm-gtk' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBNM_GTK_CFLAGS
and LIBNM_GTK_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

... and the cycle is complete, it loops like this (presumably) forever :/

Comment: package 'libnm-gtk' = `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libnm-gtk.pc` provided by the package `libnm-gtk-dev` .

Comment: Hey @KnudLarsen , I'm not sure what you mean by that :(

Comment: If you want "package libnm-gtk" you will have to do `# apt install libnm-gtk-dev`

Comment: @KnudLarsen This results in the same loop as described above. Don't want to sound mean, but did you read the question?

Answer (score 3):

Your problems are caused by your repository setup: `libnma-dev` is being installed from Debian 11 (or perhaps unstable), but `libnm-gtk-dev` is being installed from Debian 9. Installing one removes the other, because they are incompatible.

You need to choose one release of Debian or the other; you can’t mix both and expect everything to work.