# How to understand this output of apt-get unmet dependencies - X: Breaks: Y (< version) but Z is to be installed

Tags: apt, package-management, version, configure

I'm getting the following error when trying to install `libnm-gtk-dev`, but I'm having trouble understanding it:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gir1.2-nm-1.0 : Breaks: gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 (< 1.8.0-2) but 1.6.2-3+deb9u2 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

What exactly does it mean?

The error will temporarily go away if I run `sudo apt-get install gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0` - then `libnm-gtk-dev` installation will complete if run again, but it gets removed once I install my next missing package (`libnma`)... and I get the above mentioned error again, stuck in a loop.

So I'm probably doing something wrong, **maybe I need to downgrade a version or something?**

A question describing what happens if I `sudo apt-get install gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0`, with full console outputs can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/663866/looped-when-trying-to-install-network-manager-sstp-dependencies-as-hinted-by?noredirect=1#comment1248867_663866).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message means that `gir1.2-nm-1.0` either is installed or should be installed, but its metadata indicates that it breaks (*i.e.* shouldn’t be installed with) `gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0` before 1.8.0-2, and `gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0` 1.6.2-3+deb9u2 is supposed to be installed.

Specifically in this case, `gir1.2-nm-1.0` is the new name of the `gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0` package, and the former replaces the latter. The former is available from the Debian 9 backports repository, which isn’t enabled by default; instead of trying to install `gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0`, you should ensure that all the relevant Network Manager packages are installed in consistent versions, by adding

```
-t stretch-backports
```

to the `apt` command line when it gets confused.